# iOS: Notification sound is not working on physical device but working on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am running my app on iPhone 5s, but a notification sound is not working. It is working fine in the iOS Simulator. I don't know why it is not working on device, I am using the following code

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Value 1", @"Value 2", nil];
    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array forKey:@"payload"];
    [localNotification setUserInfo:data];

    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"Local notification received." ];
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open App"];
    [localNotification setHasAction:YES];
    [localNotification setAlertTitle:@"Local Notification"];

    [localNotification setAlertLaunchImage:@"AppIcon"];


    [localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1];

    localNotification.soundName = @"beep.wav";
    [localNotification setFireDate:fireDate];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
```

Comment: Have you checked Settings > Notifications and ensured that the app is allowed to play notification sounds?

Comment: Yes, app allowed to play notification sound.

Comment: Make sure your mute button is OFF in the device aswell

Comment: I have checked that already.

Comment: your sound file are copy on app

Comment: check the name of the file "beep.wav" file name are case sensitive on device,  but on simulator they are not case sensitive.

Comment: Sound is working fine on iPhone 4s but not working on iPhone 5s